# Laravel Collections - Using Except on multidimensional collection

Tags: php, laravel, multidimensional-array, collections, except

Is there any method to remove properties from multidimensional collections?

e.g I have

```
public function getPossibleAnswersAttribute()
{
    return collect([
        [
            'option' => 'A',
            'answer' => $this->answer_1,
            'points' => $this->answer_1_value
        ],
        [
            'option' => 'B',
            'answer' => $this->answer_2,
            'points' => $this->answer_2_value
        ],
        [
            'option' => 'C',
            'answer' => $this->answer_3,
            'points' => $this->answer_3_value
        ],
        [
            'option' => 'D',
            'answer' => $this->answer_4,
            'points' => $this->answer_4_value
        ]
    ]);
}

public function getPossibleAnswersWithoutPointsAttribute()
{
    $answers = $this->getPossibleAnswersAttribute()
    ->except(['0.points']);
    return $answers;
}
```

I'm trying to get the same collection but without the points key/property.

I know I could do it something like

```
->map(function ($item) {
    unset($item['points']);
    return $item;
});
```

However I'm hoping there is a more fluent way of doing this, as I've found I can do `->except(['0.points']);` which removes it from the first, I was thinking is there like a magic keyword which counts as a key? similarly to `->except(['#.points']);` so it does it for each?

Answer (score 0):

For now (Laravel 5.3) there is really nothing simpler than this `map` (or `transform`) method. For sure nothing that's as easy to understand when you come back to the code later.

You could extend `Collection` though, and implement wildcards in `except` similarly to how for example `pluck` does it, but for me that's an overkill.